# How to forward port for server socket using python codes?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I'm very new to socket programming and just tried to write a simple server/client script. When I tried to communicate with them in my own device, it worked. But when I gave my script to my friend so we would communicate remotely, it didn't work (I didnt use `'localhost'` as `hostname`).

Then he forwarded a port using HTTP interface of his router and tried to connect it with a website that tests if a port is forwarded, it was positive (my script didn't connect but this is not our topic).

So I realized I have to forward the port that my server is going to use as well! But the router that I'm using doesn't belong to me, so I can't reach the HTTP interface. In this case my program has to forward a port. But I don't know how to do it and I could not find an example or one that is at my level.

I think this is possible, because apps we use do it every time. I just need some help to figure it out. Thanks...

My little script:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print('1. Server')
print('2. Client')
r = int(input("I'm going to be... "))

if r == 1:

    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = int(input('My port will be... (0 for auto) '))
    s.bind((host, port))
    sockName = s.getsockname()

    print("\nYour Hostname: %s \nYour Port: %d" % (sockName[0], sockName[1]))

    #s.listen(int(input('Listen for ... clients')))
    input('Enter to listen...')
    print('Listening...')
    s.listen(1)

    for i in range(1):
        client, address = s.accept()
        print("{}:{} connected!".format(address[0], address[1]))

        message = input('Your message (/c to close): ')
        if message == '/c':
            client.send(message)
            print('You sent: ', message.encode('UTF-8'))
        else:
            client.close()
            s.close()
            break;


elif r == 2:

    host = input('The Hostname of Server is... ')
    port = int(input('The Port of Server is... '))

    print("\nServer's Hostname: %s \nServer's Port: %d" % (host, port))

    input('Enter to connect...')
    s.connect((host, port))
    print('Connected!')

    message = s.recv(4096)
    print('Server: ', message.decode('UTF-8'))
```